# Not getting the start or create a test option in sitecore 8.1

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, ab-testing, abtest

I am trying to do AB testing with workflow in Sitecore 8.1. I have already created  the test variants in Test the Component Box. Those variants are also stored under the Test Lab in the Marketing Control Panel. But if i am trying to save the item those variants are not visible in experience editor  and i am not getting any notification for submit or create test option. Can anyone please tell me what can be the reason and how i can get the Preview and start test dialog box. Is this any access/permission related issue?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a custom workflow?  If so, you have to have the Approve with Test command added.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Are you able to see floating toolbar in Exp? editor. if yes, select the component you are testing. In the floating toolbar use the up and down arrows to preview each test variation